# Linked the css file in django html template but no output

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

I linked my django html template with the css file, but there is no error and no changes in the page. And when I write the same css code in the same html file under the  tag, it works correctly, can someone please guide on what is going wrong?

Attaching the code of html file and settings file.

**HTML File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>TPC - Student Dashboard</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
          ::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
            color: white;
            opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
          }
          
          :-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
            color: white;
          }
          
          ::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
            color: white;
          }
        
        
        *{
            background:#E7E9F0;
            font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        </style>
        <link rel='stylesheet' src="{% static 'Dashboards/student_dashboard.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

**settings.py**

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 

DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'loginRegistration',
    'dashboards',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tpcAutomation.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tpcAutomation.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = './static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Currently, there are 2 apps in my project, namely loginRegistration and dashboards, and in both the apps, if I use the css inside the  tag, then it works properly, but when I write the same code in external css file and try to link it, there is no error but no changes also.

Thanking In Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Mainly this Happens because of the path you mentioned in the settings. You can take references from this doc.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

Plus you make can make a folder at root named 'static' and place your CSS file in that folder. Give exact path suggested as per document. Your CSS file will be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did the exact same thing mentioned in the doc, but then also it's not happening. Please, if you know some other way can you mention it? Thanking you in advance.

Comment: can you point out where your CSS file is from the root folder?

Comment: Its under the static folder, which is placed at the root level of the project.